# Debugger not working with netbeans + Lampserver

Tags: php, drupal, netbeans

I installed netbeans 7.4 in ubuntu 10.04.

My project is online e commerce site. It's developed in drupal 6 
If i click on "debug project" button its not redirected to proper page.
Please Help any one.
Is there any configuration changes required ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your project properties you have to specify the project URL, and in some case you should specify too the index file :

[image]